# How to confirm test-data from selenium webdriver is stored in the database?

Tags: database, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Interview questions:
Suppose you fill-up the fields (eg username , password etc) from Test data Excel sheet using Apache POI. After clicking on Submit button, what happens?

How do you confirm that test data from excel sheet in stored into DB?

What is interface between Selenium WD and the Database?

Comment: Use jdbc and the proper driver to connect to your database and verify the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Selenium is concerned, there is no direct facility given by Selenium to connect with any database to check any stored value.

To check the saved value you have to connect to databases depending on used db like mysql, oracle etc... you have to use supported api to make connection to database first then execute query. An example to execute query on mysql db using java with mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar, below code will return a record set which you can use like any other 2 D Array:

```
    String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";       
    Class.forName(dbClass);

    // Getting Values for dburl,dbUsername and dbPassword from configuration file
    String dburl = propertyConfigFile.getProperty("dbURL").toString();
    String dbuserName = propertyConfigFile.getProperty("dbUserName").toString();
    String dbpassword = propertyConfigFile.getProperty("dbPassword").toString();

    qaConnection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection (dburl,dbuserName,dbpassword);

    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this much like a user/manual tester would. Refresh the page, clear browser storage/cookies if you feel you should (perhaps by running some extra Javascript in the page), and go to a page where you can verify that the data was entered successfully.

Your example of username/password should be especially easy to test: they should be able to be verified by logging in with those credentials. Of course there could be a scenario where you don't let the user see or verify what they have previously done: but I suspect these are fairly rare.

I suspect also that checking exactly how the data is in the database might be beyond the usual scope of Selenium tests, and would usually be designed to pass even if you've completely re-engineered the backend. However, I see it can be argued that there is value to it being verified, especially at the initial stages of an application where the only effect of something is that something is in the database, before the UI to show it has been created. A number of databases I think offer a low-level web-ui to run queries. You could write a test that fires this up and checks that the data entered by your form is indeed in the database.